# What is an אדם כשר w.r.t. precedence for aliyos?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, torah-service

[*Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* 23:9](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur23.html#9):

> כשיש כהן בבית הכנסת צריכין לקרות אותו תחלה ואפילו אם הוא עם הארץ אלא שהוא אדם כשר הוא קודם אפילו לתלמיד חכם
>
> When there is a [*kohen*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/kohen-priest/info) in the synagogue, we must call him first [to the Torah]. Even if he is an [*am haaretz*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37965), so long as he is a כשר (*kasher*) person, he has precedence even to a Torah scholar.

What does the *KSA* mean by "a כשר person"?

Comment: Perhaps YD 340:6?

Comment: See: http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/peninim/archives/vezos63.htm.

Comment: Perhaps we may suggest a somewhat different approach. Adam kasher is a reference to a "good" Jew - not necessarily a brilliant Torah scholar, a great Torah luminary - just a simple Jew: a man of sterling character, impeccable behavior, devout and virtuous.  Instead of learning folios of Talmud, he recited Tehillim whenever he had the opportunity. He is what David Hamelech in Sefer Tehillim 15 describes as "one who walks in perfect innocence, does what is right, and speaks the truth from his heart. He does not slander, nor does he do evil or disgrace his fellowman." This is an adam kasher.

Answer (score -1):

The Aruch Ha'Shluchan (YD 119-12) in discussing the concept of "chezkas kashrus" ie. believability of a persons to claim that a food is kosher, says that in order for one to be considered an "adom kasher" one need not be exceedingly righteous and G-d fearing, rather anyone who puts on Tallis and teffilin and davens three times a day, washes their hands for meals and run their home in the spirit Judaism is assumed to be kosher.

[image]

Comment: Those are his criteria for _muchzak b'chashrus_, not for _adam kasher_. It's interesting information and they **may** be the same criteria as I seek, but I have no reason to think so.

Comment: @msh210 please elaborate as to why they are different...isnt is self evident that that which bestows presumption of kashrus is also the same criteria to be kosher? if not, why is it enough to be called b'chezkas kashrus

Comment: I haven't checked the context there but I'm **guessing** (based on the chapter number) that _kashrus_ discussed there is _kashrus_ of food, i.e. _muchzak b'chashrus_ (of a person) means "assumed to keep kosher" and not "assumed to be kosher". The _KSA_ I cite in the question calls the **person** "kosher", so if there's some "assumed to be kosher" personal status that'd be applicable.

Comment: @msh210 yes the context is of food, but the criteria of davening 3x with tallis and teffilin has nothing to do with food, furthermore the issue over there is in terms of his trustworthiness vis a vis trickery to switch the food

Comment: @msh210 the chezkas kashrus of the person directly affects the kashrus of food. why would it matter if he davens 3 times a day, why does that reflect on the kashrus of the food unless the kashrus of the food is direct outgrowth of the kashrus of the person. Keep in mind we are talking about Eid Echad Neeman B'issurim which is a sugya dealing with the chezkas kashrus of the person claiming that the food is kosher.